# PHP error handling undefined index

Tags: php

I want to handle all errors with ErrorException, so I wrote a function as my error handling function

```
function error_report(ErrorException $e)
{   
    echo 'Message:'.$e->getMessage()."<br />";
    $trace=$e->getTrace();
    foreach ($trace as $line)
    {
        echo "file:".$line['file']." line:".$line['line']." func:".$line['function']."<br />";
    }
}
```

But when I tried to catch error, the pages was like this:

> Message:include(./models/test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>       file:/www/****/src/index.php line:18 func:exception_error_transfer
>       file:/www/****/src/index.php line:18 func:autoloader
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: file' in /www/****/src/error_report.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /www/VCBS-Sub/src/error_report.php(8): exception_error_transfer(8, 'Undefined index...', '/www/****/s...', 8, Array) #1 /www/****/src/index.php(24): error_report(Object(ErrorException)) #2 [internal function]: autoloader('test') #3 /www/****/src/index.php(39): spl_autoload_call('test') #4 {main} thrown in /www/****/src/error_report.php on line 8

Comment: You have to start with the files that cannot be found.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't get it

Comment: Don't get *what*? The first error is because a file cannot be found. Make sure the path is correct and test for errors again.

Comment: @JayBlanchard first error is what I want to test. I am confused with the second error saying "Undefined index".

Comment: It is saying that you have a variable that is undefined.

Comment: But when I dump the $line, the result show it has a index named "file"

Comment: Without more code and more context it would be hard for us to guess what is going on.